# exact coordinates of gl_PointCoord?

Tags: glsl, webgl

In a vertex i give pointSize a value bigger than 1. Say 15.
In the fragment i would like choose a point inside that 15x15 square :

```
vec2 sprite = gl_PointCoord;  
if (sprite.s == (9. )/15.0 ) discard ;  
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

But that does not work when Size is not a power of 2.

(if size is 16, so (sprite.s == a/16.) where a is in 1..16 : Perfect !)

is a way to achieve my purpose where size is not of power of 2 ?

edit : i know the solution with a texture of size : PointSize * PointSize

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, gl_PointCoord);
```

but that not fit for dynamic change

edit 26 july  :

first I do not understand why it is easier to read in a float texture using webgl2 rather than webgl. For my part I make an ext = gl.getExtension ("OES_texture_float"); and the gl.readpixel uses the same syntax.

Then, it is certain that I did not understand everything but I tried the solution s = 0.25 and s = 0.75 for a correctly centered 2x2 pixel, and that does not seem to work.
On the other hand, the values: 0.5 and 1.0 give me a correct display (see fiddle 1)

(fiddle 1) https://jsfiddle.net/3u26rpf0/274/

In fact, to accurately display any size vertex (say SIZE) I use the following formula:

```
float size = 13.0;  
float nby = floor ((size) /2.0);  
float nbx = floor ((size-1.0) /2.0);  
// 
// <nby> pixels CENTER <nbx> pixels 
//
// if size is odd nbx == nby
// if size is even nbx == nby +1

vec2 off = 2. * vec2 (nbx, nby) / canvasSize;  
vec2 p = -1. + (2. * (a_position.xy * size) + 1.) / canvasSize + off; 

gl_Position vec4 = (p, 0.0,1.0);  
gl_PointSize = size;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3u26rpf0/275/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for exact values with floating point numbers is not generally a good idea. Check for range

```
sprite.s > ??? && sprite.s < ???
```

Or better yet consider using a mask texture or something more flexible than a hard coded if statement.

Otherwise in WebGL pixels are referred to by their centers. So, if you draw a 2x2 point on pixel boundary then these should be the `.s` values for `gl_PointCoord`.

```
+-----+-----+
| .25 | .75 |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
| .25 | .75 |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

If you draw it off a pixel boundary then it depends

```
++=====++=====++======++
||     ||     ||      ||
||  +------+------+   ||
||  |      |      |   ||
++==|      |      |===++
||  |      |      |   ||
||  +------+------+   ||
||  |      |      |   ||
++==|      |      |===++
||  |      |      |   ||
||  +------+------+   ||
||     ||     ||      ||
++=====++=====++======++
```

It will still only draw 4 pixels (the 4 that are closest to where the point lies) but it will choose different gl_PointCoords as though it could draw on fractional pixels. If we offset `gl_Position` so our point is over by .25 pixels it still draws the exact same 4 pixels as when pixel aligned since an offset of .25 is not enough move it from drawing the same 4 pixels we can guess it's going to offset `gl_PointCoord` by -.25 pixels (in our case that's for a 2x2 point that's an offset of .125 so  (.25 - -.125) = .125 and (.75 - .125) = .675.

We can test what WebGL is using by writing them into a floating point texture using WebGL2 (since it's easier to read the float pixels back in WebGL2)

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    return alert("need WebGL2");
  }
  const ext = gl.getExtension("EXT_color_buffer_float");
  if (!ext) {
    return alert("need EXT_color_buffer_float");
  }
  
  const vs = `
  uniform vec4 position;
  void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 2.0;
    gl_Position = position;
  }
  `;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_PointCoord.xy, 0, 1);
  }
  `;
  
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  const width = 2;
  const height = 2;

  // creates a 2x2 float texture and attaches it to a framebuffer
  const fbi = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, [
    { internalFormat: gl.RGBA32F, minMag: gl.NEAREST, },
  ], width, height);

  // binds the framebuffer and set the viewport
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, fbi);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  test([0, 0, 0, 1]);
  test([.25, .25, 0, 1]);
  
  function test(position) {
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {position});
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

    const pixels = new Float32Array(width * height * 4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 2, 2, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, pixels);
    
    console.log('gl_PointCoord.s at position:', position.join(', '));
    for (y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
      const s = [];
      for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        s.push(pixels[(y * height + x) * 4]);
      }
      console.log(`y${y}:`, s.join(', '));
    }
  }
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

The formula for what `gl_PointCoord` will be is in [the spec section 3.3](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf)

[image: gl_PointCoord formula]

so following that a point drawn .25 pixels off of a 0 pixel boundary for a 2 pixel width point

```
drawing a 2x2 at .25,.25 (slightly off center)
// first pixel

// this value is constant for all pixels. It is the unmodified
// **WINDOW** coordinate of the **vertex** (not the pixel)
xw = 1.25

// this is the integer pixel coordinate
xf = 0

// gl_PointSize
size = 2

s = 1 / 2 + (xf + 1 / 2 -  xw)  / size
s = .5    + (0  + .5    - 1.25) / 2
s = .5    + (-.75)              / 2
s = .5    + (-.375)
s = .125
```

which is the value I get from running the sample above.

`xw` is the window x coordinate for the **vertex**. In other words `xw` is based on what we set `gl_Position` to so

```
xw = (gl_Position.x / gl_Position.w * .5 + .5) * canvas.width
```

Or more specificially

```
xw = (gl_Position.x / gl_Position.w * .5 + .5) * viewportWidth + viewportX
```

Where `viewportX` and `viewportWidth` are set with `gl.viewport(x, y, width, height)` and default to the same size as the canvas.

Comment: how do you calculate xw ?

Comment: It's `gl_Position.x` converted to window coordinates. In the example above we're drawing to a 2x2 pixel canvas. We set `gl_Position.x` to 0.25. If it we set `gl_Position.x` to 0 that would be the center of the canvas so in window coordinates that's 1,1 for a 2x2 canvas. If the canvas width was 10 then `gl_Position.x = 0` would be `xw = 5`., `xw` depends on our canvas size. `xw = (gl_Position.x / gl_Position.w * .5 + .5) * canvas.width`.   `gl_Position.x = 0.25` so `(0.25 / 1 * .5 + .5) * 2` = `(0.125 + .5) * 2` = `0.625 * 2` = `1.25`.

Comment: xf=gl_FragCoord.x-0.5;